# Python Pyplot Scatterplot with USA State markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I am trying to create a scatterplot using Python Pyplot.  I am new to using Python and wanted to know you to include the USA state abbreviations as the markers for my scatterplot where the x and y data has states as a data field. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Try this piece of code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_coords = [0.13, 0.22, 0.39, 0.59, 0.68, 0.74, 0.93]
y_coords = [0.75, 0.34, 0.44, 0.52, 0.80, 0.25, 0.55]
xy_name = ['AK', 'TX', 'CS', 'AH', 'DG', 'PL', 'JK']

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.scatter(x_coords, y_coords, marker='s', s=50)

for x, y, z in zip(x_coords, y_coords, xy_name):
    plt.annotate(
        '(%s)' % (z), 
        xy=(x, y), 
        xytext=(0, -10),
        textcoords='offset points', 
        ha='center', 
        va='top')

plt.xlim([0,1])
plt.ylim([0,1])
plt.show()
```

Results in

[image]